# What language was this form created in?

Tags: forms

I saw a form on Qdoba.com. There is effect where if you click on a checkbox, the checkmark slides up and then if you uncheck it, the checkmark slides down.

Here is a link to the form: http://www.qdoba.com/menu-nutrition/burritos-menu-nutrition

I would like to know what language this was created in and if possible, how might I best approach recreating this.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: i think it's    jQuery

Comment: jQuery is not a language, but this library is propably used there.

Answer (score 1):

It's done with JavaScript (powered by jQuery, but this is unnecessary).

However, a similar effect can be achieved with plain CSS, as shown [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/US8Lw/), by using the `:checked` selector.

Answer (score 0):

HTML, looks like it uses CSS and jQuery (plugin).  Looks like a few different types of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the language, but this effect is accomplished with a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). One image consists of a blank area with a checkmark below. When the user clicks on the checkbox the image slides upward so the checkmark appears to have been animated in. (Note also that the checkbox is a `<div>`, not an actual `<input type="checkbox">`; if you recreate something like this, be sure to consider the accessibility implications of using something other than an `<input>` as a checkbox.)